# Questions regarding Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am currently trying to use Regular Expression to check if my structured message is valid.

my Pattern is

```
"(Sent: )(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\s+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}))( From: )(\\d{6})"
```

my Message is

```
"Sent: 2015/01/19 21:36 From: 000001"
```

it seems like my regular expression keeps returning false.

My message is constructed using "Sent: "+now.format(date)+" From: "+id, where
now is a Date object using the format ("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"). And id is dynamical object.

I would appreciate if someone is able to pin point my mistake

Following is a sample code for the above questions:
SimpleUDPC.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleUDPC{
    private static String currentDateTime(){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");     
        String sentence ="Sent: "+currentDateTime()+" From: 000001 Data: 0000";
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sentence.getBytes(), sentence.getBytes().length, IPAddress, 9876);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

SimpleUDPS.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SimpleUDPS{
    private static final String PATTERN = "(Sent: )(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\s(\\d{2}:\\d{2}))( From: )(\\d{6})( Data: )(\\d+)";
    private static void processReading(String message){
        System.out.println(message.matches(PATTERN));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            processReading(new String(receivePacket.getData()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should escape the `/`.

Comment: Instead of /\, try \/.

Comment: How exactly are you using this regex? It should match, and even the `.matches()` method should work if used on exactly the message you posted (however, any additional character would cause it to fail). Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I guess the message is been transmitted through a UDP protocol. does UDP adds special character at the back of my message?

Comment: @newComer For me it works fine: `String s = "(Sent: )(\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\s+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}))( From: )(\\d{6})";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(s);
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Sent: 2015/01/19 21:36 From: 000001");
    System.out.println(m.find());` returned `true`

Comment: @Ruud his tags show that he's programming in Java.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your `receivePacket.getData()` try to print it ?

Comment: @chsdk i was thinking about it too. maybe my message is too short and my receiveData have size of 1024, causing the string to have original message + junk... wild guess.

Comment: @maro slash `/` is nothing special in java; no need to escape it.

Comment: @Bohemian Shouldn't forward slash be escaped in regex? [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) warns me about it.

Comment: @maro the forward slash has nothing to do with regex. Some languages (eg java script) use them to *delimit* regexes, but the slash has no special meaning in the actual regex. RegExr, rubular and other online testers assume you'll be delimiting your regex will slashes because most visitors use javadcript, so they impose that delimiter

Comment: @Bohemian oh I see.. I assume then that RegExr is implemented in JavaScript and that's why it warns me about the forward slash. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression. It is returning your structured message correctly for me

```
(Sent: )(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\s(\d{2}\:\d{2})\s(From: )(\d{6})
```

Comment: OP's regex already matches the message. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Why escaping slashes and colon?

Comment: hmmmm however java requires double \ for meta characters. Example \\d for digit

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within the `byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];`

As my send message might not require so much size.

Still working on it myself.

Hope this helps anyone who is still working on it